# Post values by using a table on a view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, post, model-view-controller

I have a table on my view and I pass a model to this view on tbody I get values from the model and a select where I get values from a viewbag. I want to relate the values that are on each row something like Metadisciplina.Nome with the selected value on ViewBag.Docente.... Per each row I will get something like a list I don't know. Right now I have a method where I get two different types of lists where in one I get the model and in the other the values from the select option... But using this two cycles and a lot of if's I just can have one of my ideas... Or I can get for the same Docente value each Metadisciplina.Nome or for each Metadisciplina.Nome get different Docente values... I want to have the possibilty to have both Metadisciplina.Nome with different Docente values and Metadisciplina.Nome with the same Docente values.. The user will decide that...

**View**

```
@model IList<ModelsLibrary.Turno>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"> 
</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ano Letivo</label>
                <select name="anoLetivo" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Ano"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ano Curricular</label>
                <select name="ano" class="form-control">
                    <option>-Select-</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Semestre</label>
                <select name="semestre" class="form-control">
                    <option>-Select-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Escolhido" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label>Disciplina</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Turno</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Tipologia</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Docente</label>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].TurnoId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].MetaDisciplina.Nome)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].MetaDisciplina.Nome)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].LetraTurno)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Tipologia.Tipo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="DocenteId" asp-items="ViewBag.Docente"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IList<Turno> Turno, IList<int> DocenteId)
    {
        var turnodocente = new List<TurnoDocente>();

        foreach (var item in Turno)
        {    
            foreach (var ite in DocenteId)
            {
                if(!turnodocente.Any(x=>x.DocenteId == ite && x.TurnoId == item.TurnoId))
                {
                    turnodocente.Add(new TurnoDocente
                    {
                        TurnoId = item.TurnoId,
                        DocenteId = ite
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        HttpResponseMessage responsemeta = await HttpRequestBuilder.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/TurnoDocente", turnodocente);
        responsemeta.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result]

I expect to get the values without the red cross not all.... This is one of the options.. In here I just have an example but I try another way to do the if clause but the result is not what I want... And and didn't really know how I can  get the values that are related per each table row...

Comment: Not real clear on what you are going for, but I suspect you may want to conditionalize your inner loop. Perhaps something like `foreach (var ite in DocenteId.Where(d => d.TurnoId == item.TurnoId)`. Otherwise you may be running into the issue of passing multiple models to the POST. Best solution for that is to use a ViewModel.

Comment: What happens if you do `SaveChangesAsync` before this `responsemeta` stuff (of which it is unclear what it does)?

Comment: Someone knows if i can use groupBy method on this case?